# Find inner product that meets primary decomposition criterias

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, direct-sum, primary-decomposition

Let $W_1, W_2$ be subspaces over $\mathbb C$ and let $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$

Assume $\langle\cdot{,}\cdot\rangle_1$ is the inner product on $W_1$ and $\langle\cdot{,}\cdot\rangle_2$ is the inner product on $W_2$.

a. find an inner product $\langle\cdot{,}\cdot\rangle$ on $V$ such that it meets the following criterias:

- $W_2 = W_1^\perp$
- for every $u, v \in W_k$ ($k = 1,2$) then $\langle u{,} v \rangle = \langle u {,} v \rangle_k$

b. explain if the inner product you have found is the only one possible.

my first intuition was that the **standard** inner product satisfies these criterias, since both subspaces are $T$ Invariant with different eigenvectors, but i still think i am missing something, mainly because of the second question...
I would be happy for any explanation or clarification... thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by ***the standard*** inner product here?   For a general vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, there is no canonical basis, so there is no notion of a *standard* inner product.  As for your problem, try to expand $\langle u_1+u_2,v_1+v_2\rangle$ under the criterias in (a), where $u_1,v_1\in W_1$ and $u_2,v_2\in W_2$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\oplus$? Why not define $\langle (w_1,w_2), (v_1,v_2) \rangle = \langle w_1,v_1 \rangle + \langle w_2, v_2 \rangle$?

Comment: @Batominovski i was referring to the complex dot product

Comment: @copper.hat direct sum of subspaces

Comment: What is a standard inner product, what is $T$, are $W_1,W_2$ distinct spaces or are they subspaces of a larger ambient space?

Comment: Is the inner product on $W_1$ defined on $W_2$? There are many details missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only *specific* spaces have 'standard inner product' (via their 'standard basis'),  e.g. $\Bbb C^n$.

**Hint:** 2. is more immediate: the given conditions make a unique possibility for the value of
$$\langle v_1+v_2,\ w_1+w_2\rangle$$
where $v_i\in W_i$.

For 1. prove that $\langle, \rangle$ defined this way is indeed an inner product.

Comment: I don't see how this can work if the $W_k$ are subsets of the same space but the subspaces are not orthogonal. The orthogonal requirement will bot be satisfied with the above then.

Comment: Then the inner product on the ambient space  doesn't satisfy the conditions.

Comment: That was presumably the point of the question.